# Sublime Text 2 focus sidebar on opening

Tags: sublime-text-2

Is it possible to auto focus the side-bar upon opening? I am not able to form a proper command in my keymap file...

I need to combine

```
toggle_side_bar
```

with

```
focus_side_bar
```

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646552/is-it-possible-to-chain-key-binding-commands-in-sublime-text-2.  Change `reveal_in_side_bar` to `toggle_side_bar`

**Edit:** It wasn't working for me either, but I thought it was something I was doing.  Anyway, this works (for now):

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ToggleSideBarAndFocusCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("toggle_side_bar")
        self.window.run_command("focus_side_bar")
```

Run in python terminal with:

```
window.run_command("toggle_side_bar_and_focus")
```

Keymap:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+9"], "command": "toggle_side_bar_and_focus" },
```

Comment: Is this working for you? I can't seem to get it right. This is what I've got: https://gist.github.com/3995023; does nothing

Comment: Working for me on ST3 but this is flawed in a small way. It toggles the Side Bar visibility but doesn't toggle the focus. When you toggle it to the closed state, the focus remains there.

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote a new plugin to do exactly the same you mentioned, take a look

https://github.com/miguelgraz/FocusFileOnSidebar

Comment: Yes I catched it from the Package Control's RSS :) Will check it out, thanks!

Comment: Hope it can be useful, anything please feel free to ping me! =)

Comment: @Miguelgraz Unless I'm missing something, your plugin only works if the opened file is present in the sidebar project (even with **View > Side Bar > Show Open Files** enabled . The OP asks about opening the sidebar and focusing it (the last selected item, anyhting).